# Getting X Y Coordinates into PHP variables on Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, php, variables

The following script moves a ball from one location to another inside a box.

I would like to gather the coordinates of where the mouse is clicked inside this box and convert the X and Y coordinates onclick over to PHP variables so some additional PHP code can process this.

How can this be done please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Move to Click Position</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#contentContainer {
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#thing {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    transition: left .5s ease-in, top .5s ease-in;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="contentContainer">
    <img id="thing" src="//www.kirupa.com/images/smiley_red.png">
</div>

<script src="//www.kirupa.com/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script>
var theThing = document.querySelector("#thing");
var container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");

container.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

function getClickPosition(e) {
    var parentPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);
    var xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x - (theThing.clientWidth / 2);
    var yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y - (theThing.clientHeight / 2);

    theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
    theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";
}

// Helper function to get an element's exact position
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;

  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      // for all other non-BODY elements
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }

    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can then process these in the other script I have.

If someone can explain how this can be achieved it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: functionality like this would be better if you handle them with client side scripting rather than php

Comment: You can use ajax calls to pass the X, Y values to PHP. However for PHP to make an update for the user you will most likely need to refresh the page. So as previous comment said maybe try to do the whole process in JavaScript instead. Ofcourse you could do your PHP magic and save it in a database and retrieve the new data with another ajax call.

Comment: hi @Vishwa It would be but I need them in a PHP process

Comment: hi @Cray I would like the value to remain, and then when I have a submit on a form, the values pass to another page. If that helps?

Comment: So you are submiting a form on every click? Anyways make 2 hidden input fields on your form and save X, Y values in those fields on click events. Then submit the form whenever needed.

Comment: @Cray I want to do it after they have chosen the final location. Not on every click. Hope that makes sense. They can position the dot, and when they are happy they submit the form and then I get the x and y coordinates.

Comment: Have the form submission trigger some JS that pulls the X and Y locations prior to the form submit. Include the values in the form data.

Comment: @user3783243 Sounds good, Its just I am not proficient in JS to do that. I know PHP really well. If you can answer the question with detail I will Choose you for the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked through and found a solution if anyone is after doing the same thing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <title>Move to Click Position</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin: 30px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #contentContainer {
        width: 614px;
        height: 864px;
        border: 5px black solid;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url(Sample-Contract-Agreement-Letter.jpg) top left no-repeat;
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #thing {
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        transition: left .5s ease-in, top .5s ease-in;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="contentContainer">
    <img id="thing" src="//www.kirupa.com/images/smiley_red.png">
</div>

<script src="//www.kirupa.com/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var theThing = document.querySelector("#thing");
    var container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");

    container.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

    function getClickPosition(e) {
        var parentPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);
        var xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x - (theThing.clientWidth / 2);
        var yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y - (theThing.clientHeight / 2);
        document.getElementById('myField1').value = xPosition;
        document.getElementById('myField2').value = yPosition;
        theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
        theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";
    }

    // Helper function to get an element's exact position
    function getPosition(el) {
      var xPos = 0;
      var yPos = 0;

      while (el) {
        if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
          // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
          var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
          var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

          xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
          yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
        } else {
          // for all other non-BODY elements
          xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
          yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
        }

        el = el.offsetParent;
      }
      return {
        x: xPos,
        y: yPos
      };
    }
    </script>

    <form action="test.php" method="post">


    <input type=”hidden” value="" id="myField1" name="myField1">
    <input type=”hidden” value="" id="myField2" name="myField2">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```